# ViewBag - converts to html entities

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to convert results from a query into json.

```
    string esql = "select d.dpr_ts, d.dpr_close from Entities3.dpr_mm as d";//where dpr_qot_id=2029543939 and dpr_ts>='" + start + "' and  dpr_ts<='" + end + "'";
    EntityConnection econn = new EntityConnection("name=Entities3");

    econn.Open();

    EntityCommand ecmd = econn.CreateCommand();
    ecmd.CommandText = esql;
    EntityDataReader ereader = ecmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
    Console.WriteLine("Entity SQL Result");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (ereader.Read())
    {
        if (i > 0) result.Append(","); i++;
        result.Append("['" + ereader.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString() + "'," + ereader.GetValue(1) + "]");
    }
    ViewBag.ChartData = "[" + result.ToString() + "]";
```

I want to save it in ViewBag. But the result string looks like : `[&#39;10.01.2011&#39;,3,9990],[&#39;11.01.2011&#39;]` (so `"'"`  is converted to `&#39;`). How can I avoid it?

BTW: Can I generally do this task better?

Comment: Well, I'm trying. Is it still not as it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. transform the result from sql into an object, even a dynamic object will work.
2. put the object in the `ViewBag`
3. in the view render the object as JSON using `Json.Net`

here is an example

controller

```
var data = GetDataFromDatabaseAndMapToObject();
ViewBag.TheData = data;

return View(model);
```

view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.Serilaized(ViewBag.TheData));
    //use json however you would like.
</script>
```

Comment: Could you give me more clues for GetDataFromDatabaseAndMapToObject();?

Comment: that is just a place holder for the logic needed to query the database and create the model you will want to serialize.

Comment: there are very few scenarios where there is only one right way. there are some improvements you can make to your ado.net code, but that's not the point of this post. right now we are just trying to get json into the template.

Comment: and what should be the data here?

Comment: i don't understand the question. the data is what you need it to be.

Comment: i did string at the beginning, which doesn't work as i wish it does. what should i put in the data now?

Comment: data is an object, or array or whatever. `JsonConvert.Serialize(data)` will convert the model to JSON. `@Html.Raw` will out put the raw result. typically the value is html encoded to prevent malicious code. `@Html.Raw` does not encode the output.

Comment: now im getting name this error: 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: you probably need to include the namespace. if that doesn't work start a new question.